# Как добавить class к элементам в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Когда я записал элементы в массив, я помещаю их в `LocalStorage`, при загрузке страницы я хочу добить тем элементам которые находятся в массиве активный класс, как это можно сделать? `favModules = ["#elem-1", "#elem-2", ...]`, не используя `es6`. почему то у меня в консоли ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: favModules.each is not a function`, буду признателен, если подскажите где ошибся.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('favModules')) {
        var favModules = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favModules'));
        favModules.each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < favModules.length; i++) {
  $(favModules[i]).addClass("selected");
}
```